# ようと followed by a noun

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence in a manga when the main character was trying to make a call from a prison phone; however she is knocked down by another prisoner before she can do so and is said:

> 『ここの電話は全て予約制だ！囚人みんなが電話をしたがっている　しかも**いくらかけようと自由**ってんなら混雑ができるのは当たり前だろ』

The part in bold is giving me a hard time. I understood 「かけよう」in the "make a phone call" sense of 「掛ける」. I haven't come across 「～ようと」constructions that are not followed by a verb so far. I got the general meaning of the pharse but cannot make out the grammar behind aforementioned construction.

In short my question is: What is the 「～ようと」construction in above stated sentence.

Comment: Would you understand the meaning if I told you 〜ようと means the same thing as 〜ても？

Comment: I think 自由(だ) is adjective verb.

Comment: @sbkgs4686 Would you agree that the translation could be something like: „No matter how much the others (囚人) are phoning if it would be completely free (not in a money sense) there would be...” (not attempting to sound natural in any way)

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to say correctly, then yes. いくらかけようと自由 / いくらかけても自由 would translate to something along the lines of "(you're) free to call as much as you'd like/want". That sentence as a whole would then become something like "and besides, if (I/they/we) were to say / make it so that you guys're free to call as much as you wanted, you can bet your bottom there would be way too many people trying to make calls all at once."

Comment: I think かけようと　is abbreviation from かけようとしても that is MAYBE comes from  かけようとすると. I dont know whether it is helping or not.